# How to use @openlayers-elements/maps web component in deno?

Tags: jsx, web-component, deno, hono

How to use web components in deno project? I use hono framework.

I want to use:
@openlayers-elements/maps: https://www.webcomponents.org/element/@openlayers-elements/maps

I have a route for example:

```
app.get("/home", async (c: Context) => {
    return c.html(index.layout({
      content: (
        <>
          {header()}

          {await home()}
        </>
      ),
    }));
  });
```

and the `home` function where I want to display a map. How to use @openlayers-elements/maps?